# mgcv: Specifying factor-smoother interactions for "global" grouped smooths

Tags: r, time-series, smoothing, gam, mgcv

I've found the [Hierarchical GAM pre-print](https://peerj.com/preprints/27320/) (and [GH repo](https://github.com/eric-pedersen/mixed-effect-gams)) of Pedersen et al. extremely helpful in modeling inter-group variability in functional responses, but I've hit a stumbling block.

I have some time series data (counts over time) with the following basic expectations:

1. there exists a global functional response of interest between counts and time;
2. the global function varies among a few "fixed" groups (2-5), likely with similar smoothing parameters;
3. there seems to be a systematic trend in the "random" deviations from this global function from year to year (i.e., the shape of the functional response is drifting in a consistent direction); but
4. the trend in annual deviations applies differently to the "fixed" groups.

Here I try to illustrate with a contrived example, as I fear my description falls short. I simulate 20 replicate (annual) time series for two "fixed" groups/treatments. In the control (trt == 0), there is little annual variation. In the treatment (trt == 1), there is a systematic trend in the shape of the response.

```r
library(reshape)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2020)
n_yr <- 20
n_trt <- 2
n_x <- 10
dat <- tibble(yr = rep(seq(0, n_yr - 1), n_trt)) %>%
  expand.grid.df(tibble(x = rep(seq(0, 1, length.out = 10), n_trt),
                        tweak = c(rep(0, 15), rep(0.02, 5)),
                        trt = rep(0:1, each = n_x)), .) %>%
  mutate(e = rnorm(n_x * n_yr * n_trt, 0, 0.3),
         y = 3 + 9 * (x - tweak * yr) - 1 * (x - tweak * yr)^2 - 10 * (x - tweak * yr)^3 + e,
         fyr = factor(yr),
         ftrt = factor(trt),
         fty = factor(interaction(trt,yr)))
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_line(aes(group = yr, colour = yr)) +
    facet_grid(trt ~ .) + theme_bw() +
    scale_colour_gradient("Year", low = "#2166ac", high = "#b2182b")
```

[image]

What is the appropriate mechanism to capture the functional response(s) of interest as well as model inter-annual variation in the response that varies between groups?

My best guess is to model a factor-smooth interaction (using treatment as a `by` variable) for my "global" smooths. But how then to model annual deviations from these separate smooths?

A simple factor-smooth (`fs`; `?factor.smooth.interaction`) by year from a single global response seems inadequate:

```r
library(mgcv)
m <- gam(y ~ s(x, by = ftrt, k = 5) + ftrt + s(x, fyr, bs = "fs", k = 5, m = 1),
         data = dat, method = "REML")
plot(m, pages = 1)
```

[image]

A `fs` interaction by treatment-year seems more appropriate:

```r
# Different smoothing parameters by treatment
m1 <- gam(y ~ s(x, by = ftrt, k = 5) + ftrt + s(x, fty, bs = "fs", k = 5, m = 1),
          data = dat, method = "REML")
p <- plot(m1, pages = 1)
```

[image]

The plot below better illustrates the differences in annual deviations from the treatment smooths between treatments, as well as the "trend" in the shape of those devations for the treatment group:

```
df <- data.frame(p[[3]], 
                 fty = rep(levels(dat$fty), each = 100),
                 trt = rep(rep(0:1, each = 100), 20),
                 yr = rep(0:19, each = 200))
ggplot(df, aes(x, fit, group = fty)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = yr)) +
  scale_colour_gradient("Year", low = "#2166ac", high = "#b2182b") +
  facet_grid(trt ~ .) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

So my questions:

1. Is a base set of factor-smooths for fixed treatment group (`s(x, by = ftrt)`) appropriate vs. some kind of global smooth (`s(x)`)?
2. Is there a better way to allow for "random" annual variation in smooth shapes separately by treatment groups?
3. Is there any way to capture the "trend" in changing shape for certain groups, i.e., to model a linear change in smoothing parameters or similar?